# How to get Caller Name using twilio SMS Reply?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

When I buy the number I use

```
 var purchaseOptions = new PhoneNumberOptions();
    purchaseOptions.PhoneNumber = commandArgument;
    purchaseOptions.VoiceUrl = LeadsModuleDomainNamePublic.Trim() + "/ProcessCallTwilio.aspx";
    purchaseOptions.StatusCallback = LeadsModuleDomainNamePublic.Trim() + "/ProcessCall.aspx";
    purchaseOptions.SmsUrl = LeadsModuleDomainNamePublic.Trim() + "/TwilioReply.aspx";
    purchaseOptions.VoiceCallerIdLookup = true;
```

When I get number then use this code.

```
     foreach (string var in Request.Form)
    {
        if (var == "CallerName") { CallerName = Request[var]; }
    }
```

but its not give me caller name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// This code work for me    
// Download the twilio-csharp library from twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Twilio;
    using Twilio.Rest.Lookups.V1;
    using Twilio.Types;

    public class Example
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
            const string accountSid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
            const string authToken = "your_auth_token";

            TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

            var phoneNumber = PhoneNumberResource.Fetch(
                new PhoneNumber("+15108675309"),
                type: new List<string> { "caller-name" });

            Console.WriteLine(phoneNumber.CallerName["caller_name"]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

By looking at your code I'm making the assumption you are using the [C# Library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp) correct?

And I'm thinking you're trying to get the caller name from a call you're receiving? If that's the case, when you receive a call, Twilio will pass a number of variables back to you which are related to that call. `CallerName` is not one of them.

An incoming call is modelled [like this](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/blob/ab0983ae00269746c5dbeb891955ae3edd83796d/src/Twilio.Api/Model/Call.cs), and these are all the variables Twilio will pass when it makes a request to your server.

I think what you may be looking at is the [CNAM Lookup](https://www.twilio.com/lookup) on the [Lookup API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups). With that, you can get the caller name information when it is available.

Hope this helps you

Comment: I need code for incoming SMS not for incoming call.

Comment: That is the exact same process. You can use the lookup API to get the information from the number who sent the SMS message.